# Android: ViewPager inside a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have an activity  that has a LinearLayout which in turn is split in three more LinearLayouts .

I want to make the top-third horizontally 'swipable'. The solution I assume to make a view swipable is to implement ViewPagers. I am not able to figure out how to get a ViewPager inside a LinearLayout. Also I would rather NOT have tabs on top of each view inside ViewPager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution will be to use a `ViewFlipper`:

```
<LinearLayout ... >
<ViewFlipper>
<RelativeLayout>
<!-- your design here (part1)-->
</Relativelayout>
<RelativeLayout (redifine with same id)>
<!-- your design (part2)-->
</RelativeLayout>
<!--repeat for further parts of your design-->
</ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect Sir! Works like charm. ViewFlipper combined with Gesture detection

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to figure out how to get a ViewPager inside a LinearLayout

Same way you get anythign else into a LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout ... >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager ... />
    <!-- other children -->
</LinearLayout>
```

It won't have tabs on top since those are not part of ViewPager itself. I recommend spending time looking at the [`ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) docs.