# Android ViewPager, first View is not swiping?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

i have a ViewPager component inside a FragmentActivity and am filling it with FragmentStatePagerAdapter and Fragments.

The thing works, there is just one thing i don't want, but maybe it's expected behaviour:

The first Fragment / View stays static and does NOT MOVE, when i swipe to the next Fragment / View.
The next fragment get's swiped above the first one.
When i swipe back to the first fragment, it's the same.
The first one seems to sit UNDER the other fragments and does not move at all.
It just looks like the other fragments get pulled away like a blanket above the first one...

How can i have the first fragment being moved in and out like the other fragments?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Voting to close as requested by OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, seems like Android's WebView does not like "position: fixed" in the content's CSS!
So that is the answer: If you position your HTML contents with CSS "position: fixed", the WebView in a Android ViewPager will NOT move! Seems like a bug to me...

This question may be closed, thank you everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Look at "Customize the Animation with PageTransformer" here http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

It will explain you how to make animation between views. And if you want the default behaviour, just remove the call to

```
setPageTransformer();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, the standard implementation of the ViewPager component in this example behaves exactly like i want it to: The first view also slides in and out of the viewport. But in my implementation, it does not! It just sits there without moving. How can this be!? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ViewFlipper. It will give you ease to play around with each layout too.
Try my solution here in this question-- [ViewFlipper implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726503/android-viewpager-inside-a-layout/17728297#17728297)

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't answer my question. See below, i found a standard implementation example of the ViewPager component, and it does work exactly like i want it to. But in my application, it does not. My code is essentially the same as in the android developers example linked below. Any ideas, what could keep the first view in my ViewPager from moving!?